# MOSFET and Falstad

Tags: motor, control

I have a circuit to control a small motor which is modelled in Falstad. See model below. when I start the simulation the voltage on the MOSFET side of the motor is low and then climbs until it reaches a high voltage about 6.4 volts. Is this a problem with the circuit or a problem with Falstad?

```
$ 1 0.000005 69.34413510434165 52 5 50 5e-11
f 304 240 352 240 32 1.5 0.02
w 352 256 352 304 0
w 352 224 352 176 1
174 176 208 176 288 1 10000 0.11390000000000002 Resistance
w 64 160 64 144 0
w 64 144 176 144 0
w 176 144 352 144 0
w 64 272 64 304 0
w 304 240 304 256 0
w 304 256 192 256 0
w 176 208 176 192 0
w 352 144 384 144 0
w 448 128 448 176 0
w 384 144 384 128 0
415 352 176 448 176 0 200 7.4 0.15 0.15 0.02 0.05 1 0
w 384 128 448 128 0
w 112 176 112 160 0
w 112 160 64 160 0
w 176 176 176 192 0
r 176 176 112 176 0 6800
v 64 272 64 160 0 0 40 6.7 0 0 0.5
w 64 304 64 352 0
w 352 304 352 352 0
w 64 352 176 352 0
w 176 352 352 352 0
O 448 128 480 112 1 0
O 352 224 416 240 1 0
O 304 256 304 288 1 0
O 176 176 224 176 1 0
O 176 352 176 384 1 0
O 176 304 128 304 1 0
w 176 304 176 352 0
g 352 352 352 384 0 0
o 26 1 0 4098 10 0.1 0 1
```

or

[Falstad simulation](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWEA2AnNAzAFi2DCxItsxkkEAmEcyagUwFowwAoAMxAyJAq1vyq9+VMNCQxIFFgHdOlHgmRyqXLFBnKevTWADsS1nrV6lFSAA5w+nucsRC8KNGYZU8dx6oAlOgGcAlr4ALgCGAHYAxnQayMbItLHgOOqyiWDJJklqkBqZ6WoCWSkoahS6VImqxVVCnNwUitX1jWCogo05splmdtatVJ06yRjmxsmDOHYUlpNWSoMjYwWj4NPquEiFmbOZtGa0utDZzuInTpLnSBALK2BrO2uDzCJ9d+Dxxc-vCXG0T30AgxtdQAJzm4K+uxQ5jgLAAbiUeOVEaQ-lAQHwUNBdOi-mIYgVuJV5At5FVCoVBsSXkpKblrBSySSWAB5DFYKYzGHgN7XVmaCjaXCmTF8tk1Ro1WzgdRsvLWQXGPqy8FbBm3FWZKp3Szaz4M7ha5kAc00jJUKz+LAA9jwDOi+Kg7HjruAWEA).

[image]

[image]

Comment: What behaviour were you expecting?

Comment: I was expecting a stable low valtage not a climbing one. if you leave it to run then it will eventually get up to 6.4V

Answer (score 2):

When using mosfets in the fallstad simulator, they default to a bet value of around 20m. This is quite small and is around the range of small signal mosfets.

In your case, you are driving an high power load, so you need to modify the beta value to be a bit more beefy

This simulator has a beta value calculator page at https://www.falstad.com/circuit/mosfet-beta.html, where you can fill in the properties of your mosfet to calculate its beta value.

For example, taking the values of the datasheet of the n-channel mosfet IRLZ44NPBF, gives us a beta of 6.993006993006993, which is 300 times higher than the default value fallstad uses

(Also note that the DC motor fallstad uses also requires editing to the parameters of your motor, the default values are not really suitable for most situations)

After editing the mosfet to simulate an IRLZ44NPBF and the DC motor to represent the ones from [this page](https://ctms.engin.umich.edu/CTMS/index.php?example=MotorPosition&section=SystemModeling), [we now have a simulation that actually behaves like real world](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=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)